# Committing to a secret shared value

Tags: secret-sharing, commitments

Suppose I run a multiparty protocol. At the output stage, I have the function output in a secret shared manner among all parties.

Now I want all the parties to commit to their value of the secret shares

In essence, suppose every party $P_i$ has a share $Y_i$.
Every party should commit their value = $Com(Y_i)$

My problem is that I want to ensure that party $P_i$ doesn't commit to an incorrect value

$Com(Y'_i)$ s.t $Y'_i \not= Y_i$

before moving to the next stage in the protocol. I also do not want to reconstruct the output value until a later stage in the protocol.

Is there any efficient way in which you can perform such a commitment while ensuring that every party commits to the right value?

Comment: If reconstruction takes everyone and the storage requirements are nearly minimal, then that's simply impossible. ​ (xor sharing satisfies those two conditions.) ​ If the secret sharing scheme instead merely doesn't provide a way to verify shares individually, then I don't see any way to avoid having the multi-party computation protocol internally "reconstruct the output value". ​ ​ ​ (... continued) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ (I _might_ be able to prove that, for example, [Shamir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) has no such way if I had a definition of what it means for a multi-party computation protocol internally "reconstruct the output value".) ​ The obvious alternative is having the _initial_ multi-party computation protocol output [encapsulations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.7813&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of the shares to everyone and give each party decapsulating info for its share. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly, you want each party to commit to a share that is the result of some MPC. You want to be able to check that the commitment is valid without reconstructing the value that the share comes from?

Comment: @mikeazo exactly

Comment: Is the purpose of this to short-circuit the computation if someone is not behaving properly? It has been a while since I looked into some of the dishonest majority protocols like SPDZ, but I believe it has a MAC that gets updated during computation that can be checked.

Comment: Yes exactly!  The problem with using SPDZ in this context is that in order to check the consistency of the shares at the output stage, you need to reconstruct the output value which I don't want!